# When accessing front-end SPA-links from browser, back-end fires finding no route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a working front-end single-page-application written in JS (ReactJS), and a working back-end in Phoenix (Elixir). Everything works out fine as long as navigation happens within the application. However, when I try to access a page in the SPA from the browser, I get a route error fired from Phoenix. For example:

```
no route found for GET /search (PhoenixApp.Router)
```

is what I get when I access http://localhost:4000/search from the browser.

When I access http://localhost:4000/search from the navigation inside the SPA, I get a working page from ReactJS.

So my question: How can I get ReactJS to get the page, rather than Phoenix?

Comment: You need to set your server to respond with landing page so that SAP can take it over and bootstrap stuff properly. So GET `/` and `/search` yields the same response from server .

Comment: SPA : is it deployed on Nginx ?

Comment: Try pointing a wildcard route to the route of the home page, e.g. `get "/*anything", PageController, :index`.

Comment: Perfect! The wildcard route works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this for Single-Page Applications is to serve the exact same thing on every GET route as you're serving on `/`. You can add a wildcard GET route to your Phoenix Router and point it to the same thing as the route for `/`. If `/` is served from `PageController`'s `index` function, you should add:

```
get "/*anything", PageController, :index
```