# Serving a Single Page App using Phoenix Framework causes two get requests

Tags: single-page-application, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to get a phoenix app serving a React SPA, following along with this advice: [When accessing front-end SPA-links from browser, back-end fires finding no route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782764/when-accessing-front-end-spa-links-from-browser-back-end-fires-finding-no-route)

I've set this up successfully before following the above solution so I know its worked in the past.

Heres the relevant bits from my router:

```
pipeline :browser do
  plug(:accepts, ["html"])
end

...
scope "/" do
  pipe_through(:browser)
  get("/*anything", TexWeb.StaticController, :index)
end
```

My first client side route is at `/start`. When I go there, I find that I get two get requests in the log:

```
Generated tex app
[info] Running TexWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000
[info] GET /start
[debug] Processing with TexWeb.StaticController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"anything" => ["start"]}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 141µs
[info] GET /static/js/main.8e39f2e0.js
[debug] Processing with TexWeb.StaticController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"anything" => ["static", "js", "main.8e39f2e0.js"]}
Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 183µs
```

I've copied the exact same SPA code to another phoenix 1.3 instance and it successfully loads the `start` route. Interestingly, this log looks like:

```
[info] GET /start
[debug] Processing with TexappWeb.StaticController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"anything" => ["start"]}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 17ms
[info] GET /
[debug] Processing with TexappWeb.StaticController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"anything" => []}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 129µs
```

I'm pretty sure that the line:

`Parameters: %{"anything" => ["static", "js", "main.8e39f2e0.js"]}`

is the cause of my problems.

But where do I start to look to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to change this line in `endpoint.ex`

From:

```
plug(Plug.Static, at: "/", from: :tex, gzip: false, only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt))
```

To:

```
plug(Plug.Static, at: "/", from: :tex, gzip: false)
```